# Android Layout Issue:Screen not visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to implement something like the filters in zomato app where on selecting the filters the first screen moves showing up only a part of the first screen and whole of second screen where we can select the type of filter which upon selecting gives us all the types of filters after moving the first and the second screen both.

What I have done is I have the inner screens(filter type and filter option) as two relative layouts which are invisible and then i slide them and make them visible by changing the margins of it's layout parameters and requesting the layout .

While showing up the third screen(filter options) the second screen is not visible even if i provide the correct margins .

Can anyone help?

EDIT CODE :

private class SlidingAnimation extends Animation {

```
    private float mainViewStartX, mainViewEndX;
    private float sideViewFromX, sideViewToX;
    private float sideView2FromX,sideView2ToX;
    private View slideInView,slideOutView,slideInView2;


    public SlidingAnimation(float fromX, float toX, float sideViewFromX,
            float sideViewToX,float sideView2FromX,float sideView2ToX, int duration,View slideInView,View slideOutView,View slideInView2) {
        setDuration(duration);
        this.slideInView =  slideInView;
        this.slideOutView = slideOutView;
        this.slideInView2 = slideInView2;
        mainViewEndX = toX;
        mainViewStartX = fromX;
        slideOutViewLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) slideOutView.getLayoutParams();

        this.sideViewFromX = sideViewFromX;
        this.sideViewToX = sideViewToX;
        slideInViewLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) slideInView.getLayoutParams();     

        if(slideInView2!=null){
            Log.w(null,"Side View two also exists");
            this.sideView2FromX =  sideView2FromX ; 
            this.sideView2ToX =  sideView2ToX;
            slideInView2LayoutParams = (LayoutParams)slideInView2.getLayoutParams();
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
            Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

        if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
            // Applies a Smooth Transition that starts fast but ends slowly
            if(slideInView2==null){
                slideOutViewLayoutParams.rightMargin = (int) (mainViewStartX + ((mainViewEndX - mainViewStartX) * (Math
                        .pow(interpolatedTime - 1, 5) + 1)));               
                slideInViewLayoutParams.rightMargin = (int) (sideViewFromX - ((sideViewFromX-sideViewToX) * (Math
                        .pow(interpolatedTime - 1, 5) + 1)));
                slideOutViewLayoutParams.leftMargin = (int)- mainViewEndX;              
                slideInView.requestLayout();
                slideOutView.requestLayout();
                Log.w(null,"Slide Out Right Margin:"+slideOutViewLayoutParams.rightMargin);
                Log.w(null,"Slide Out Left Margin:"+slideOutViewLayoutParams.leftMargin);
                Log.w(null,"Slide In Left Margin:"+slideInViewLayoutParams.leftMargin);
            }
            else{
                slideOutViewLayoutParams.rightMargin = (int) (mainViewStartX + ((mainViewEndX - mainViewStartX) * (Math
                        .pow(interpolatedTime - 1, 5) + 1)));               
                slideInViewLayoutParams.rightMargin = (int) (sideViewFromX + ((sideViewToX-sideViewFromX) * (Math
                        .pow(interpolatedTime - 1, 5) + 1)));
                slideOutViewLayoutParams.leftMargin = (int)- mainViewEndX;      
                slideInViewLayoutParams.leftMargin = (int)-sideViewToX;
                slideInView2LayoutParams.rightMargin = (int) (sideView2FromX - ((sideView2FromX-sideView2ToX) * (Math
                        .pow(interpolatedTime - 1, 5) + 1)));                   
                slideOutView.requestLayout();
                slideInView.requestLayout();
                slideInView2.requestLayout();
                Log.w(null,"Slide Out Right Margin:"+slideOutViewLayoutParams.rightMargin);
                Log.w(null,"Slide Out Left Margin:"+slideOutViewLayoutParams.leftMargin);
                Log.w(null,"Slide In Left Margin:"+slideInViewLayoutParams.leftMargin);
                Log.w(null,"Slide In Right Margin:"+slideInViewLayoutParams.rightMargin);
                Log.w(null,"Slide In View 2 Right Margin:"+slideInView2LayoutParams.rightMargin);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The call :

SlidingAnimation open = new SlidingAnimation(-width+dpToPx(45), width - dpToPx(45/2), 0,width-dpToPx(45),-width+dpToPx(45),0,1000,filterTypeLayout, selectBusLayout,filterOptionLayout);

Comment: I have solved the problem . It was basically because of the different sizes of the layout . So the call to the animation that i was making was incorrect .It should be SlidingAnimation open = new SlidingAnimation(-width+dpToPx(45), width - dpToPx(45/2), 0,width-dpToPx(90),-width+dpToPx(45),0,1000,filterTypeLayout, selectBusLayout,filterOptionLayout);

Answer (score -1):

Try using two [HorizontalScrollViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html).

Add the HSVs to a FrameLayout.

Implement OnTouchListeners for the HSVs, handle the touch events and accordingly make the HSV smoothScroll to the specific position on the screen. You could specify positions based on screen width.

example: ScrollView.smoothScrollTo(4*width/5, 0);